# Unable to get example to work.

Tags: singularitygs

My HTML looks like:

```
<head>
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class='holder'>
 <div class='block-a'>A</div>
 <div class='block-b'>b</div>
</div>

</body>
```

My SCSS looks like

```
$grids: 12;

.holder {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
   @include clearfix;
  @include background-grid;
}
```

However, when I compile and view the scss, I just see A and B.  If I add a background color to block-a, it displays the background color.  Why is the background grid now showing up?

Comment: Works for me: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9582904

Answer (score 1):

you are running singularity 1.2? Then try to add aside the `@include background-grid;` mixin in the scope of your global singularity definitions also the following statement:

```
 @include  sgs-change('debug', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to add a mixin

```
@mixin clearfix {
  clear:both;
  /*-- rest of ClearFix Atributes --*/
}

.holder {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  @include clearfix
  @include background-grid(10) ;

}
```

Comment: That still does not seem to work.  clearfix was defined with @import "compass"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any result using Sass 3.3.5, Compass 1.0.0.alpha.18 and Singularity 1.2.0.

This line below Throws an Error => wrong number of arguments (25 for 1..2) for `_linear-gradient'

```
@include sgs-change('debug', true);
```

Demo:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/11350705

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if this is the identical issue referenced in [Singularity Issue #168](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/168). Please follow that issue.